# Finding the number of onto functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

The number of functions $f$ from $(1,2,\dotsc,20)$ onto $(1,2,\dotsc,20)$ such that $f(k)$ is a multiple of $3$ whenever $k$ is a multiple of $4$ is

Comment: Any thoughts?  Might be worth noting that an onto function in this case is just a permutation.

Comment: i get 5 elements in domain and 6 in codomain so how to make function onto?

Comment: You have to map $5$ elements to $6$ elements,clearly one of the $6$ elements wont be an image.

Comment: That's not the function that's onto.  $f$ must be a permutation of $(1,2,\cdots, 20)$ with certain conditions.

Comment: While every multiple of $4$ is required to map to a multiple of $3$, the converse is not required (fortunately).

Answer (score 2):

The set is finite, so $f$ is onto if and only if it is one-to-one. There are $5$ multiples of $4$ and $6$ multiples of $3$, so there are $6!$ one-to-one mappings from the multiples of $4$ to the multiples of $3$. The remaining $15$ non-multiples of $4$ must be mapped one-to-one to the remaining $15$ numbers; there ar $15!$ ways to do so. This yields $6!\times15!$ such functions.